# How to prove $\lim_{a \to + \infty}a^q \int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)dx}{x^p}=0$ when $p>q>0$

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals

I know a similar problem in demidovich's problem set #2357 about proving $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}x^a\int_{x}^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^{a+1}}dt$$it proves by dividing the integral into two parts and used two inequality to prove it less than some $\epsilon$. But the method does not apply.

My other attempts discovered $\sin(x)$ is not arbitrary and cannot be casually changed to some constant even on some intervals.

After Taylor expansion of $sin(x)$ is applied, the limit is still hard to calculate since it is a sum of an infinite series of improper integrals.

Comment: Since $\sin x$ is entire, taylor expansion may be of help. After integrating, you'll get an expression in $a$ with powers more negative than $q$ ($p>q$) from which the result follows.

Comment: Another thing you might try is L'hospital's rule by setting ${1\over a} = t$, since the fraction is of $\frac{0}{0}$ form indeterminate. For the numerator you would need Leibniz rule for differentiation of an integral. The resulting limit should become much easier.

Comment: Lastly, you could just use $|\sin x|\le 1$ in the integral and simplify.

Comment: @AritraDas the integral is from a to infinity, not near a point, how can you apply taylor expansion?

Comment: $\sin x$ is an enitre function. That means it's taylor series converges everywhere on the complex plane. So, they are defined in terms of their taylor series. That's why you can use the taylor series instead of the actual function in this question. More over, you can integrate it term by term. This is not true for all functions.